# Compiling error. Unable to copy file from bin\debug to bin\debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am relatively new to vb.net and so I apologise in advance if I omit any important details from this post. Please point out how I can better ask the question if you think I can.

For some reason when I try to compile my code I get this error:

> Error  1   Unable to copy file "C:\Documents and Settings\localuser\Desktop\EwE\Sources\PDistribute\bin\Debug\PDistribute.exe" to "bin\Debug\PDistribute.exe". Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\localuser\Desktop\EwE\Sources\PDistribute\bin\Debug\PDistribute.exe'.    ScientificInterface

Now this looks like it is trying to copy from the same location it is copyings from and that doesn't make sense to me. Why would this be and do you know how I can solve the problem?

I really don't understand much about how vb.net compiles and builds code and am new to computer science in general. Would it be worth me doing much reading about 'building and compiling' and what are the best resources?

Comment: Is your program open/running when you are trying to recompile it?

Comment: I agree with vcsjones.  If you have the exe running while trying to compile, it can give you this error.

Comment: Sounds like a bad post-build event but there really isn't sufficient info in the question.  It is pretty important to start learning about programming and your tools by making small steps.  Tinkering with custom virtual machines is skipping a couple of thousand small steps.  Tackle something smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You copy the same to the same.
After extract from your text:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\localuser\Desktop\EwE\Sources\PDistribute\bin\Debug\PDistribute.exe
C:\Documents and Settings\localuser\Desktop\EwE\Sources\PDistribute\bin\Debug\PDistribute.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Another error:

"bin\Debug\PDistribute.exe". Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\localuser\Desktop\EwE\Sources\PDistribute\bin\Debug\PDistribute.exe'

Text start  from **"**, ending **'**

You make ^C^V or write from kbd?

Answer (score 0):

Im using "Visual Studio 2015 Community Free" and "Visual Basic 2010 express" i had same kind of problem.. What i did to solve it was close Visual Basic 2010 express OR Studio version and go to my project's files and delete "Release" folders...
After that go back and build your project! It should also work :)